# Smarty Templates - Variable Inside Variable?

Tags: variables, smarty

So I am currently doing a custom WHMCS template that uses the smarty template system. One of the calls is as follows:

```
{$customfield.input|replace:'>':'placeholder="Placeholder' >'}
```

Now this works in that it sets the placeholder with the text Placeholder. What I am trying to achieve is to get the following variable inside where the Placeholder text is:

```
{$customfield.name}
```

So I need something like the following:

```
{$customfield.input|replace:'>':'placeholder="{$customfield.name}" >'}
```

but that doesn't work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to do it

```
{$customfield.input|replace:'>':"placeholder='`$customfield.name`' >"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the braces around the second variable:

```
{$customfield.input|replace:'>':'placeholder="{$customfield.name|escape:html}" >'}
```

Comment: That just shows `$customfield.name` inside the placeholder instead of the actual variable.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either :( Doesn't show any input field so I guess it breaks the templating system.

Comment: Okay let's try that last edit. Then I'm fresh outta ideas. :(

Comment: Got the answer: `{$customfield.input|replace:'>':"placeholder='`$customfield.name`' >"}`